# Does it matter where you put the pointer? (asterix) sign?

Tags: c, pointers

I Just want to know what is the difference between the following way of assigning a pointer. i was watching a C tutorial online and couldn't understand why he used the second pointer like this `char * buffer;`. Instead of `char *buffer`

Like the way I use the pointer in all my C learning. is it style?
e.g

```
FILE *pFile;

struct product *next;
```

does it matter where you put the asterix (pointer) or what is the meaning behind it?

Comment: "well-adjusted" people put the "*" in the middle like `char * p` ...;-)

Comment: C allows various  styles.  The best style is to follow your group's coding standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no difference, it's a matter of preference.

I tend to put it as `struct product* next` because it makes it clearer that the type of `next` is `product*`, AKA a pointer to a product. But different people advocate different things.

Comment: This might be confusing, when you declare multiple variables at once. For instance, with declaration as: `struct product* next, next_second;`, second variable is of type `struct product`, not pointer to it.

Comment: That's true, but this is also terrible practice in my opinion no matter how you do it, it's just really terribly opaque.